# Using ObjectCollectionValidator with MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a class that contains a property that I have decorated with `ObjectCollectionValidator`.

```
[ObjectCollectionValidator]
public List<MyDetailClass> Items { get; set; }
```

I am using this class as my model in an MVC5 application.

In my `HttpPost` action method, when MVC tries to validation my model, an exception is being thrown stating:

> A validation attribute of type ObjectCollectionValidatorAttribute cannot be used to validate values.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.NotSupportedException: A validation attribute of type ObjectCollectionValidatorAttribute cannot be used to validate values.

Is `ObjectCollectionValidator` not compatible with MVC? If not, what is the best way to approach validating this collection? Would I need to create my own custom validator? Or create a `SelfValidation` method?

Comment: The documentation for this makes it look like you need to specify the object type you're validating:  [ObjectCollectionValidator(typeof(MyDetailClass))]

Comment: Thanks for responding.  Unfortunately, I tried this and it does not work.  Since the exception being thrown is a NotSupportedException, I'm assuming that MVC doesn't support it.  I may have to write my own custom validator.